# How to fetch data from text field without using any buttons?

Tags: android, textbox, enter

user enter's the 5digit number into the text field and without pressing any button it must be refelected on the simulator. I know how to write the data into simulator I just wanted to know how to fetch this user data as soon as he enters 5 digits without clicking any button that is, on pressing enter the data in the text field must be fetched.

Comment: html, javascript, c#, other languages? need more context to be able to provide you some information

Comment: See my answer. Using jquery.

Comment: Please check the check mark next to may answer as this answers your question.

Comment: Sir please tell me how to do this in android

Comment: Oh..That is completely different question. This answered your question. Please check the check mark next to my answer. And then take that and ask a new question with that question. We only answer one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

**YOU ASKED:** "I just wanted to know how to fetch this user data as soon as he enters 5 digits without clicking any button that is, on pressing enter the data in the text field must be fetched."

**HERE IS HOW**, using the keypress event. I also limited the text input to 5 characters as well with  maxlength="5".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").keypress(function(e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if (key == 13) // the enter key code
        {
            if ($("input").val().length == 5) {
                //you get the value with $("input").val()
                alert($("input").val());
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter 5 characters: <input type="text" id="input" maxlength="5">
```